# How to handle timeout in FreeRTOS - wake up task from interrupt before vTaskDelay expires?

Tags: task, delay, interrupt, freertos

Can I wake up task before vTaskDelay expires?

I have code like this:

In the task (hnd_uart_task) code:

```
transmit_frame();
vTaskDelay(100);  // task should wait 100 ticks or be woken up by uart ISR
parse_response();
```

UART Interrupt:

```
// if byte was received
BaseType_t xYieldRequired = xTaskResumeFromISR(hnd_uart_task);
portYIELD_FROM_ISR(xYieldRequired);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `vTaskDelay()`, you can use task notifications with timeout.

USART Interrupt:

```
// if byte was received
BaseType_t xHigherPriorityTaskWoken = pdFALSE;
vTaskNotifyGiveFromISR(hnd_uart_task, &xHigherPriorityTaskWoken);
portYIELD_FROM_ISR(xHigherPriorityTaskWoken);
```

Task Code:

```
transmit_frame();
ulTaskNotifyTake(pdTRUE, 100);
parse_response();
```

`ulTaskNotifyTake(pdTRUE, 100)` returns when a task notification is received from the ISR, or when 100 tick timeout period elapses.

But as @Jacek Ślimok pointed out, a *byte-by-byte* parsing may not be good idea. The exact method depends on the protocol used. But in general, you set up your DMA or interrupts to fill a reception buffer with incoming bytes. For example, when parsing Modbus frames, you can use idle line detection hardware interrupt and give notification to a task which parses the RX buffer.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try with ulTaskNotifyTake(...). I'm working on Modbus and I have parsing done (I'm porting code from PIC18 to STM32F7). For character timeout I'm using built-in USART RTO interrupt, but this timeout unfortunately works between bytes, not when there is no byte received at all.

Comment: @Kamil , Although the Modbus specs allow some gaps between the bytes (was it 1.5 char-time?), I ignored these gaps between bytes. I've never come across a serial transmitter that puts gaps between the bytes (disclaimer: my field experience is limited). So I implemented RTO interrupt for detecting 3.5 char-time gaps between the frames. Some STM32 parts (like F407) don't even have RTO feature, and I use idle detection on them. 1 char-time is out of specs, but seems to work okay.

Comment: I tried this and it worked. I have suprisingly simple modbus master transport implementation. I know that RTO is not implemented in some devices. According 1.5 char silence - I also never implement this. Modbus in the matter of transport is a bit awkward protocol.

Answer (score 2):

No, because that's not what `vTaskDelay` was meant to be used for.

The closest solution to yours would be to create a semaphore that you attempt to take inside the task with a 100ms delay and that you give from ISR. This way the task will block for a maximum of 100ms waiting for semaphore to be given, after which it'll unblock and resume execution anyway. If it's given earlier, it'll unblock earlier, which is what I assume you want.

*However*, from what you've written I assume you want to achieve something like the following:

- Send some data over UART
- Wait for response
- As soon as response is received, do something with the response

In this case, doing both blocking and parsing in the same task is going to be hard (you reaaaalllly don't want to do **any** sort of parsing inside of your ISR). I'd therefore recommend the following "layout" of two tasks, an interrupt and one shared smepahore between the two tasks:

1. "High level" task (let's call it *ApplicationTask*) that can do the following:

- Construct whole frames and request them to be sent over UART (add them to some kind of queue). This "construction of whole frames" and sending them over to the other tasks would usually be wrapped into some functions.
- Will block waiting for response
- Will receive already parsed data (full frame or object/structure holding that parsed data)

2. "Byte level" task (let's call it *ByteTask*) that can do the following:

- Has a queue for transmitted data (queue of frames or queue of raw bytes)
- Has a queue for received data
- "Pushes" data from "data to be transmitted" queue into UART
- Parses UART data that appears in "received data" queue and gives semaphore to unblock the *ApplicationTask*

3. UART Interrupt:

- Only transmits data that it's told to transmit by *ByteTask*
- Pushes received data into *ByteTask* receive queue

4. Shared semaphore between *ApplicationTask* and *ByteTask*:

- Whenever *ApplicationTask* wants to "wait to receive response", it attempts to take this semaphore. Maximum blocking time can be used as a "response receiving timeout".
- Whenever *ByteTask* receives and parses enough data to decide that "yes, this is a complete response", it gives this semaphore.

This above is a super simple example of something that should be easy enough to scale to more tasks as you develop your application. You can get a lot more fancy than that (e.g. *ByteTask* handling multiple UARTs at the same time, have a pool of semaphores used for blocking for multiple tasks, do some more sophisticated message dispatching etc.), but the example above should hopefully give you a better idea of how something like this can be approached.

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation. I wonder why didn't you suggest `ulTaskNotifyTake(pdTRUE, 100)` as @Tagli did. I think this will use less resources.